# Is possible to "isolate" some audio frequency?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, wavelength, biology

I want to know if is possible to "isolate" some audio frequency for certain human that only this human can hear this "frequency spectrum", some animals can hear certain frequencies of spectrum and human have their own spectrum, if is possible to a certain human to hear a spectrum that others can not, so basically what I have been looking is to "isolate" some frequency that only one isolate human can hear that audio "frequency spectrum"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Individual humans can have odd capabilities, but I've don't think what you postulate is known to happen. Humans commonly can hear a range of frequencies that decreases with age (in my youth, I could hear well into the "ultrasonic" spectrum). There's no hard, absolute, cutoff: louder sounds may be heard over a wider range of frequencies.

Comment: What I I'm looking for is like a channel where, that only one person can hear and others, not like a private channel of communication.

Comment: @Jonatas Hearing doesn't really work in "channels".

Comment: Did you know if Is there something like channels?

Comment: @jonatas, human hearing has nothing like channels. it isn't possible to send sound to someone so only they can hear it unless they are young enough to hear at 12kHz while all the oldsters next to them cannot. Even then, all the youngsters- not just one of them- would get the message too.

Answer (score 1):

> .. is possible to a certain human to hear a spectrum that others can not,

No.

Human hearing is limited to a frequency range of about 20Hz to 20kHz and that frequency range is determined by the physiology of the human auditory system. Since this is constructed the same way for all humans, this range is quite consistent. It does vary a bit by age at the band edges but not all that much. If you can hear  anything  meaningful, most other people will hear the same thing.

You could of course deploy technology: transmit in the ultra sound range (say from 30kHz to 40 kHz) and than wear an ear piece that frequency shifts the sound from the microphone. But that requires the transmitter and receiver to "agree" on a protocol, so you might as well just use Bluetooth or something like this.